# RequestUri in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Below is the code in asp.net framework.

```
    protected HttpResponseMessage Created<T>(T apiResponse, ObjectId id) where T: ILinking
    {
        //var builder = new UriBuilder();

        Uri uri = new Uri(this.RequestUri(), id.ToString());
        apiResponse.get_Links().Add(new ApiLink(uri, "created", HttpMethod.Get));
        HttpResponseMessage message = base.Request.CreateResponse<T>(HttpStatusCode.Created, apiResponse);
        message.Headers.Add("Location", uri.ToString());
        return message;
    }
```

I want to migrate it in asp.net core. I google it a lot but unable to find any solution. How can I declare this.RequestUri() in asp.net core?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am relatively new in the .NET world but i started my adventure with ASP.NET Core 1.0 6 months ago (So I don't have the references with the previous versions), but I guess you want to get the actual URI of the user ?
In this case, the following code can help you: `string  host = context.Request.Host.ToString();`
`string  path = context.Request.Path.ToString();`

Comment: How did you original `RequestUri()` method look like? It's not a standard method. Yet, assuming it only returned the current request URI you can simply use `this.Request.RequestUri`

Comment: What is "this"?

Comment: See GetEncodedUrl
https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/UriHelper.cs

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core includes some new features that make returning a "Created" response easier.

In your controller, you can add an action like this.

```
[HttpPost, Route("create")]
public ActionResult CreateMyObject([FromBody]Creature newCreature)
{
    string id = // some new object id
    var newPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.Path, id);
    return this.Created(newPath);
}
```